# Is it possible to covert multiple sheet excel into one?

Tags: libreoffice, gnumeric

Is it possible to covert a multiple sheet excel file into one sheet, and have the original sheet name as a column in the final sheet?

So if you have multiple sheet excel A and B where all sheets have the same column names, you combine them, add a column lets call it category and it will have value of A or B.

Can that be done using LibreOffice or gnumeric or any software available on Ubuntu or should I do it programmatically?

Comment: If I understand your scenario correctly, it should be straightforward to create one worksheet in LibreOffice Calc and copy the data from the Excel worksheets, appending each Excel sheet's data in turn by pasting these into the Calc worksheet.  You can also add a column to the Calc sheet and label it Category.  However, it isn't clear what you mean by the new column having the value A or B.  Perhaps a cut-down (just 2-3 rows and columns of two Excel sheets), as an example of the original Excel sheets and the resulting  Calc worksheet might clarify what you are trying to do.

Comment: Perhaps some sample data for Sheet A and Sheet B and what the end result needs to be would shed some light on your predicament.

Comment: Export both sheets as csv, cat the 2 files together and import in libreoffice.